# Save snapshot to different region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

Here is my connection code. The "RegionEndpoint" doesn't seem to have any effect on where snapshots are stored. If I don't set it though, it says, "No Regional Endpoint or Service Url configured".

What is it for and how do I target a region? Do I need to create a snapshot first and then copy it to the correct region?

```
private static IAmazonEC2 GetEc2Client()
{
    var settings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

    AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(settings["AWSAccessKey"], settings["AWSSecretKey"]);

    var region = (RegionEndpoint) Enum.Parse(typeof(RegionEndpoint), settings["TargetRegion"], true);

    return AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonEC2Client(awsCredentials, region);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to create the snapshot first, then copy it to the desired region, if you want a snapshot to be available in a region other than the one where the source volume is.

Snapshots are always initially created in the same region as the volume being snapshotted, and presumably this has to do with the way snapshots work -- creating a snapshot in the local region only copies blocks that weren't already captured by a snapshot of the same volume that hasn't been deleted.      At a low level, the local snapshot is actually a list of pointers to the data blocks that comprise that snapshot, which EBS has stored in S3 on your behalf (and you can't see them in the S3 console).   When you create a volume from the snapshot, the new volume's data is lazy-loaded onto disk from S3.  If you made numerous consecutive snapshots from the same volume with little or nothing actually changing on the volume, you wouldn't be billed duplicate storage charges in the local region.  Blocks are purged from snapshot storage only when no remaining snapshots reference them.

With a snapshot copied to another region, all of the data is apparently copied into S3 by EBS in the distant region before the snapshot copy is marked as complete and then volumes from that copy are loaded from the data blocks that are now duplicated in that region's S3 backing store.  The specific details, of course, are not public.

Answer (score 1):

Snapshots are stored in the same region as the instance used to create the snapshot.  So if you have an instance located in the eu-west-1 region then when you create a snapshot it will also exist in the eu-west-1 region.

You need to specify a region in order to tell AWS which region you want your instances, etc. located in. Some SDK's default to using the us-east-1 region since that was the first region Amazon launched AWS in. Some SDK's & tools explicitly require you to specify a region and don't use a default.

If you're unfamiliar with regions and what purpose they serve then I'd strongly suggest you read the [AWS documentation on regions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html) to get a basic understanding of them.

Comment: "You need to specify a region in order to tell AWS which region you want your instances, etc. located in." Sorry for being dumb, but my instance is located in a different region to the value I pass in and its still able to make a snapshot of its volume.

Comment: I'm not sure it matter. Just seems to be a way into the API. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html